# Make the title of the ActionBar clickable

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is it possible to make the title of the ActionBar clickable?

I guess there is some `android.R.id.XXXX` to identify the title in `onOptionsItemSelected`, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

There is android.R.id.home for the icon but I am not aware of any for the title text.

Comment: Hey Manfred! I'm aware of the id for the home icon, but definitely couldn't find anything for the title. I'm starting to hesitate about its existence.